# Adding an ASP.NET Core Web API project to an existing .NET Worker Service project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Worker Service project that is calling some external APIs, modelling data, and then POSTing that data to our internal APIs. Everything has been working fine but one of the external APIs has enabled webhooks, so I can receive data updates without polling their API for data. In order to subscribe to their API, I need to expose an HTTP Endpoint to receive updates.

I have added an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project to the existing solution and added it as a reference into my worker service project. Where I am confused is how to initialize both projects in my WorkerService `Program.cs` file. I'm trying to just add a `UseStartup` function call but .NET 6 no longer has a `startup.cs` class to reference.

Worker Service `Program.cs`:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
    webBuilder.UseStartup<APIStartup>();   // APIStartup doesn't exist, not sure what to reference
})
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
})
.Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

WebAPI `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I'm lost because one uses `IHost` and one uses `WebApplication` builder so I'm not sure how I can initialize my Web API project alongside my Worker Service project

Comment: I have different executable apps (worker + API) that share lots of the same code.  This is because the security methods for workers are not necessarily the same as those for APIs.  For example, an API has a bearer token, in an HTTP header.  Where would the worker store the bearer token (yes, in a message header, but it's slightly different).  How would the user claims get into the IPrincipal?

Comment: @fubar92 - do you plan to run the API and Worker service in the same process?  Or will the API and Worker be deployed as separate services?

Comment: The fact that this is causing problems for you should probably be a hint that you shouldn't be trying to do it. A worker service is not a web application, and vice versa. You have two separate applications, make them two separate applications and allow them to communicate by e.g. a message bus.